# Ocorreu uma violação da restrição de integridade referencial

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, entity-framework

Estou recebendo este erro cada vez que tento atualizar um objeto na minha base de dados SQL via *EntityFramework*, o erro é o seguinte:

> Ocorreu uma violação da restrição de integridade referencial: Os valores de propriedade que definem as restrições referenciais não são consistentes entre objetos principais e dependentes da relação.

O erro só acontece quando eu altero a *FK VideoID* desta maneira no *Controller*:

```
foo.Video = vid;
foo.VideoID = vid.VideoID;
```

Se não mudar estes valores, o erro não acontece, por isso alguma coisa está mal nesta lógica mas não percebo o que. Eu passo o objeto `foo` para o método que faz o update, que é o seguinte:

```
 public void UpdateCompany(Company foo)
    {

        Company c = GetCompany(foo.CompanyID);

        if (c.AddressID != null)
        {
            Address a = new AddressesManager().getAddress((Int32)c.AddressID);
            foo.Address.EntityKey = a.EntityKey;
        }

        if (c.VideoID != null)
        {
            Video v = new VideosManager().GetVideo((Int32)c.VideoID);
            foo.Video.EntityKey = v.EntityKey;
            context.Detach(c.Video);
        }

        if (c.Video1 != null)
        {
            Video v2 = new VideosManager().GetVideo((Int32)c.PreRoleID);
            foo.Video1.EntityKey = v2.EntityKey;
            context.Detach(c.Video1);
        }

        company.EntityKey = c.EntityKey;

        context.Detach(c.Address);
        context.Detach(c);

        try
        {
            context.AttachTo("Companies", foo);
            foo.SetAllModified(context);

            if (foo.Address != null)
            {
                context.AttachTo("Addresses", foo.Address);
                foo.Address.SetAllModified(context);
            }

            if (c.VideoID != null)
            {
                context.AttachTo("Videos", foo.Video);
                foo.Video.SetAllModified(context);
            }

            if (c.Video1 != null)
            {
                context.AttachTo("Videos", foo.Video1);
                foo.Video.SetAllModified(context);
            }

            // novo
            var qup = from p in context.CompanyProducts
                      where p.CompanyID == c.CompanyID
                      select p;

            if (qup.Count() != 0)
            {
                DataLibrary.CompanyProduct cp = qup.First();
                cp.RecordState = 1;
            }

            //novo
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }

    }
```

**Imagens da base de dados:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O erro só acontece quando eu altero a FK VideoID desta maneira:

foo.Video = vid;
foo.VideoID = vid.VideoID;  ????????? onde você fez isso?

Comment: Publique também a estrutura das tabelas em questão. Provavelmente a coluna VideoID não tem referência em outra tabela.

Comment: Sinceramente olhei esse seu código e não entendi o motivo de tanta complicação.... você esta usando o lazy load certamente para ter que ficar anexando e desanexando as entidades do contexto que a meu ver não tem necessidade.  Já que você faz a buscar de uma Company c = GetCompany(company.CompanyID); ... use ela que já tem suas propriedades do contexto mapeadas .... só alterar o que foi modificado.

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza eu faço isso no Controller (no POST) e depois passo o objeto `foo` (que é uma Company) para o método seguinte. Quanto à questão da implementação do **update**, não fui eu criei, já estava feito e também não consegui entender o motivo de ter sido feito assim...Vou colocar uma imagem da tabela